# How to manage 5 different table views (and detail views) from a tab-based view controller in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In other words, I'm looking to figure out how to use a 5 tab tab-based view controller, that, when i touch on one tab, I am brought to a table view- static array- that would then have a detail view controller.

So tab- table view- detail view.

I am new at swift so I'm sure how to phrase this properly, but I'm wondering how to manage/add multiple table views to my project using tabs.  I've register for an online iOS swift course, but they only touch upon single-view applications.  Any help or references would be greatly appreciated.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var taskArray:[TaskModel] = []


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    let task1 = TaskModel(task: "Study French", subTask: "Verbs", date: "04/14/2014")
    let task2 = TaskModel(task: "Eat Dinner", subTask: "Burgers", date: "01/14/2014")


    taskArray = [task1, task2, TaskModel(task: "Gym", subTask: "Leg Day", date: "01/14/2014")]

    tableView.reloadData()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "showTaskDetail" {
        let detailVC: TaskDetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as TaskDetailViewController
        let indexPath =  self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
        let thisTask = taskArray[indexPath!.row]
        detailVC.detailTaskModel = thisTask
    }


}

//UITableViewDataSource
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return taskArray.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let task = taskArray [indexPath.row]
    var cell: TaskCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell") as TaskCell

    cell.taskLabel.text = task.task
    cell.descriptionLabel.text = task.subTask
    cell.dateLabel.text = task.date

    return cell
}
//UITableViewDelegate

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    performSegueWithIdentifier("showTaskDetail", sender: self)

}
```

Comment: Please post the code you've tried so far.

Comment: When you say tabs, are you talking about a UITabBarController like the Facebook & Twitter apps?

Comment: this is the code I have for the table view and detail controller.  I am unsure of how to implement multiple tables/detail controllers for each tab.

Comment: Look into `UITabBarController`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to separate the concerns for a start.

A [UITabController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/) has [viewControllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITabBarController/viewControllers). Every UIViewController associated in the UITabController can have it's own implementation file and interface. There you can add [UITableView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html) and conform to the [UITableViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html).

If you want to have multiple UITableView to one UIViewController then it would be good to create custom controls with their corresponding XIB files and implementation files and load into the UIViewController. This way you can abstract and clear code between them. Also check IBDesignable and IBInspectable.

You will probably want to share data between them, either pass them via the UIViewController that include your table view controls, if you need to take action to the specific references, or create a [Repository](https://github.com/ducn/Repository-Pattern-in-Objective-C) to provide the data.

Comment: In "Every UIViewController associated in the UITabController can have it's own implementation file and interface. There you can add UITableView and conform to the UITableViewDelegate."  by implementation file and interface, which/what type of controller (if controller) are you referring to?

Comment: If you're using Storyboards, you set the UIViewController implementation file in the Storyboard interface. If you're using XIBs then you associate it with a UIViewController file.